# How to add png background image AND fill color to SVG?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I know this is possible for regular html elements, and I know how to add fill color or a background image to an SVG. But is doing both possible? I'm just trying to add a filter effect to these background(fill) colors.

```
.element {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  background-image: url('images/filter/grunge.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.

Do you mean like this?

```css
svg {
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="200">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Actually kind of...I want a custom filter based on a png. So you set this image on top of everything and it gives it the desired filter effect(whatever the png drawing is). I don't want to use CSS filters.

Comment: If you want a "background" in the SVG, then just put a rectangle or whatever at the back (ie. first element in the SVG) and apply the filter to that.